# How do I define preprocessor macros through MinGW make

Tags: mingw, c-preprocessor, preprocessor, mingw32

I've been trying to build a **make file** I generate via **qmake**, and I've tried the following but they don't seem to work.

```
mingw32-make -j8 -DDEVELOP
```

```
mingw32-make -j8 -D DEVELOP
```

But both seem to fail with the former giving me:

```
mingw32-make: invalid option -- E
mingw32-make: invalid option -- V
mingw32-make: invalid option -- E
```

followed by the `-help` messege.
And the second one begins compiling but then gets to `mingw32-make: *** DEVELOP: No such file or directory.  Stop.` and stops, failing to build the exe.

I'm using GNU MAKE 4.2.1 which was installed along side QT.

I wouldn't want to define these from my project files or in C++ as they're unique to certain builds. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Make doesn't have a `-D` parameter.
If you want to pass this to your compiler, you need to check the `Makefile` to see if there is a variable where you can add it to that is used when compiling. Usually this will be `CFLAGS` and/or `CXXFLAGS`.

Sometimes you can do

```
mingw32-make -j8 CXXFLAGS="-DDEVELOP"
```

or if that doesn't work you could try like this

```
mingw32-make -j8 CXX="g++ -DDEVELOP"
```

In the worst case you will need to manually add `-DDEVELOP` to the `Makefile` where compilation is done (look for compilation flag `-c` or other flags like `-O`).